# why is '<' binding's currentValue undefined when I pass as a literal string in angular

Tags: angularjs

Hello I have a binding say itemType:

This is how I define it in my component:

```
 bindings: {    
     itemType: '<?',
 }
```

Now for some  reason the value is not passed when I passed it as literal string as opposed to a property value, this is what I mean, let say I have a controller:

```
someController = function someController( $scope) {
            var self = this;

            self.itemType = 'someString';
```

**Working:**

```
<some-component>
        open-id="singleSelect"
        item-type="ctrl.itemType"
```

//..

```
 itemType.currentValue = 'someString'
```

**Not working:**

```
<some-component>
        open-id="singleSelect""
        item-type="someString"
```

//..

```
itemType.currentValue = undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When furnishing a literal string to a component attribute that is bound with one-way `('<')` binding, use quotes:

```
<some-component
    open-id="singleSelect"
    ̶i̶t̶e̶m̶-̶t̶y̶p̶e̶=̶"̶s̶o̶m̶e̶S̶t̶r̶i̶n̶g̶"̶ ̶
    item-type="'someString'" >
</some-component>
```

Otherwise `someString` is evaluated as a property identifier. It binds `undefined` because that property does not exist on scope.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@` binding for strings.

The `<` binding expects the argument to be a `$scope` property, and `$scope.someString` does not exist, but `$scope.ctrl.itemType` does.